# what is the reason for menuitem error in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my project there is an error occurs

```
 The name 'MenuItem' is defined in the libraries
'package:emarket_user/view/base/mars_menu_bar.dart' and
'package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_menu_bar.dart'.
(ambiguous_import at [emarket_user] lib\view\base\menu_bar.dart:10)
```

please help me to solve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class `MenuItem`  is an abstract class for describing cascading menu hierarchies that are part of a `[PlatformMenuBar]` package.
in the second line import you're importing this class in this line:

```
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_menu_bar.dart';
```

but in this line `'package:emarket_user/view/base/mars_menu_bar.dart'` you are importing from a library or class that you wrote, maybe you have wrote it and then delete it or renaming without refactoring it. try to remove that line of import or change the class name in platform_menu_bar.dart.